# Adding axes symbol to Right Triangle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I would like to achieve something like what is shown:

[image: Goal Image]

However, I'm not sure how to add the x and y labels without having to manually do everything (like I had to do for the m)

Here is my current code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
  \coordinate (C) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
  \coordinate (A) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
  \coordinate (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
  \coordinate (BL) at (-0.5,-1/3);
  \coordinate (BR) at (0.5,1/3);
  \coordinate (TR) at (0,1.088);
  \coordinate (TL) at (-1,0.42);
  \filldraw[color=cyan!40,draw=black] (BL) -- (BR) -- (TR) -- (TL) -- (BL); % block
  \node[rotate=33.69] at (-0.25,0.377) {$m$};
  \filldraw[draw=black,fill=orange!40] (C) -- (B) -- (A) -- (C); % triangle
  \draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm); % right angle
  \tkzLabelAngle(A,C,B){$\theta$};
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=.7cm](A,C,B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this two lines

```
\draw[-latex] (2,1.3)--(1.7,1.1) node[above] () {\tiny $x$};
\draw[-latex] (2,1.3)--(1.8,1.6) node[right] () {\tiny $y$};
```

at the end of your `tikzpicture` environment and you have this result:

[image]